# Flutter Image Hovering Overlay Effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-image

I am working on a flutter web project and I want to the following overlay effect over my image that whenever the cursor hovers over the image, a few buttons should show up, and the opacity of the image gets reduced (or blurred out) while hovering.

I have tried **InkWell** and **GestureDectector** but nothing seems to work.

This is basically what I am trying to achieve : [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWGLL.gif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, over time I have tried many ways and would like to share my insight in case somebody else is looking for the same solution too.

So, the basic way to achieve this is to use the **Hovering** package.
Another way would be to use **MouseRegion**.

You can use the onEnter and onExit property of [MouseRegion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) to detect when did the cursor entered and left the region/container you are trying to add a hove effect to.
You can use that to switch between your different app states.
Or it has onHover property as well, that basically tells that if the cursor is currently hovering that region or not you can use that too.

**Note:** I tried the **Listener** widget as well, but either I didn't understood it well, or it was too complicated to work with. Anyways, I couldn't achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [hovering](https://pub.dev/packages/hovering) package to achieve the hovering effect on `flutter_web`.

First, import the package:

```
import 'package:hovering/hovering.dart';
```

Add a `GlobalKey` within your `StatelessWidget`:

```
final _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

And then, use the `HoverWidget`:

```
              HoverWidget(
                hoverChild: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Hover Me..')),
                ),
                onHover: (event) {
                  _key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Yaay! I am Hovered'),
                  ));
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Hover Me..')),
                ),
              )
```

Check the example use case [here](https://pub.dev/packages/hovering/example)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Raj this is pretty simple

You just need to use Listener Widget which detects onPointerHover and update you app's state

Here is the api link follow it

[Listener in Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html)

If any difficulties comment down below